# Something wrong with data insert

Tags: php, mysql

Good day,i am trying to insert data into mysql table using php its kinda working but i can't see data in phpmyadmin

```
   <?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$con)
{
echo("not connected");
}
if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'exam'))
{
echo 'db not selected';
}
$header = $_POST['header'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$categ = $_POST['categ'];
$moder = $_POST['moder'];
$posttxt = $_POST['posttxt'];
$theme = $_POST['theme'];
$author = $_POST['author'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO postex (header,date,categ,moder,posttxt,theme,author) VALUES ('$header','$date','$categ','$moder','$posttxt','$theme','$author')";
if
(empty($header) || empty($date) || empty($categ) || empty($moder) || empty($posttxt) || empty($theme) || empty($author))
{
  echo "<Br>feel the fields!!!";

}
else{
echo("<br>added,wait for redirect");
}
?>
```

Comment: You are not executing your query, you just define a string. But when you do, you will have an sql injection problem.

Comment: so how can i actually execute it?

Comment: You should probably start with the manual...

Comment: ^ a novel idea. That thing's just "left in limbo".

Comment: you need to take care of that possible sql injection also, if you plan on going live with this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, that would probably be a good idea :-)

Comment: I'd say it would @jeroen ;-)

Comment: i don't plan using it,just a task right now is to put it into the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, before anymore wrong answers come up using `mysql_`, it's `mysqli_query($con, $sql)` that wasn't used to execute the query.

- RTM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

and take care of that sql injection that you're leaving yourself open to, if/when you go live with this.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

with a prepared statement

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

while making sure the POST arrays do contain values (and the form uses a POST method with matching named inputs) and that there are no characters passing through that MySQL could complain about, for example: apostrophes.

Escape the data going in, in any respect.

Check for errors via PHP and the query:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

---

Nota:

You should first check if any of the fields are (not) empty, then execute the query.

I.e. and pseudo conditionals:

```
if(none empty and good to go){

    // execute the query
}

else{
// do something else
}
```

Plus, if you're using your entire code inside the same file, being the form and php/mysql, then you should check if any of the POST arrays are set/not empty first. That will throw a few errors and give you undesired results.

Comment: @jeroen I wouldn't have submitted an answer if you would have ;-) I had to set the record straight.

Comment: @jeroen Oh, sorry *lol* well, I did make a comment about that under the question, but felt it should have been part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
                      <?php
              function db(){
              $servername = "servername";
              $username = "username";
              $password = "password";
              $database = "database";

              // Create connection
              $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$database);
              $conn->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); 
              // Check connection
              if ($conn->connect_error) {
                  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                  return false;
              }else{
                return $conn;
              } 
            }

    $data=db();

        $insert="INSERT INTO movies (bla1, bla2, bla3) VALUES (blavalue1, blavalue2, blavalue3)";


        $dotaz=mysqli_query($data,$insert);

if($dotaz){
echo "OK";
}else{
echo "Wrong";
}
                ?>
```